# Java Play overwrites port in application.conf

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I want to specify port on which Java Play exposes its endpoints in the `application.conf` file – complete snippet of the `application.conf`, format taken from Java Play [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ProductionConfiguration#Server-configuration-options)

```
play.server.http.port = 5511
```

However, if I run command

- `sbt run`

exposed port is 9000, not 5511.

I was able to achieve correct behaviour by running

- `sbt run -Dhttp.port=5511`

so there must be problem in the `application.conf`.
If I try to read the value programmatically, say from controller, it also gets the wrong value of 9000. However, if I add some artificial value to the `application.conf`, say `foo = "ABC"`, it correctly reads this value.

---

Java play version: 2.8.15
SBT version: 1.6.2
Plugins: only java play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per of the play [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ConfigFile#HTTP-server-settings-in-application.conf) :

> In run mode ***the HTTP server part*** of Play starts before the application
> has been compiled. This means that the HTTP server cannot access the
> application.conf file when it starts. If you want to override HTTP
> server settings while using the run command you cannot use the
> application.conf file

I would propose you do this way `sbt run -Dhttp.port=5511` as you stated earlier. If you are worried about passing everytime the arguments with run task then you can change your root project settings in the `build.sbt` file only once. Do not forget to to `sbt reload` so your `build.sbt` changes take effect.

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
   .settings(PlayKeys.playDefaultPort := 5511)
```

Another alternative : you can add the following line in your build.sbt file

```
PlayKeys.devSettings += "play.server.http.port" -> "8080"
```

Comment: Adding or appending to already existing `root` variable the mentioned `lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
   .settings(PlayKeys.playDefaultPort := 5511)` works.

Answer (score 0):

I have no direct explanations, but that's work if you put on your `application.conf` file the `http.port` variable, and not directly `play.server.http.port`.

A clue may be found in the file, on [Production Configuration page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ProductionConfiguration#Server-configuration-options), presented by

> The configurations above are specific to the Akka HTTP and Netty server backend

Comment: After chaning the line in `application.conf` to `http.port = 5511` nothing changes. Java play still uses default port 9000 instead of 5511.